# Simple crontab schedule of python script not outputting to file

Tags: python, shell, cron, scheduled-tasks

I have a python file with this content:

```
from datetime import datetime

print(datetime.today())
```

If I run this from terminal with `python3 file.py > out.txt` I will get the `out.txt` file with todays date.

I want to replicate this with cron and schedule this script to run every minute. So the crontab looks like:

```
* * * * * /path/to/python3 /path/to/file.py >> path/to/out.txt
```

Now this works and `out.txt` does get created but the file is empty and never contains any date. Why is that?

The duplicate mentioned here does not solve my issue. I have tried this with just a simple echo command scheduled every minute with cron tab and it worked.

Somehow this is a python issue. Python is hiding the output. Or there are some other permission issues.

Comment: Add the full path to the out.txt file.

Comment: that how it already is..my mistake for not including it in the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to include `2>&1` at the end of the crontab specified in order to append the printed value to the file, so your crontab should look like:

```
* * * * * /path/to/python3 /path/to/file.py >> path/to/out.txt 2>&1
```

Comment: Tried this. Still no output

Comment: The file will now contain an actual error message you can examine. See the duplicate for (lots) more.

Comment: The mentioned duplicate applies to cron jobs that are not running. I know mine is running because I see the file being created on the first minute and I have tried other tests that work (echoing every minute to file) its this specific python case that is not working.

Comment: My mistake this actually does return an error inside the out.txt. cron does not have permission to access python script.